# myfaces.sourceforge.net/tld/myfaces_ext_0_9.tld

Tags: java, jsf-2, taglib

I'm using myfaces.sourceforge.net/tld/myfaces_ext_0_9.tld in my jsp for JSF 1.1 version.
Now I want to migrate from JSF 1.1 to JSF 2.0.
And Im using the jsps as the frontend in my application.
When I replace the jsp in JSF2.0
Im getting canot find tag library exception for 
myfaces.sourceforge.net/tld/myfaces_ext_0_9.tld this tag.
Kindly, help me.
Is it replaced by any other taglib or is there any other taglib in JSF2.0?

Answer (score -1):

JSF 2.0 supports xhtml as Page Declaration language. use this instead

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
     xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
     xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
```

Comment: That's the whole problem. OP upgraded from JSP to Facelets. The mentioned old JSP tag library is not compatible with Facelets. OP is basically looking for the Facelets compatible version or alternative.